# How to display an entire bounding Box in the Frustum of the camera in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What I want is to position the camera at a certain distance and height from an game object.

The requirements are that the "BoundingBox" of the Gameobj is always visible (aligned) with the Frustum planes (see screenshot). The bounding box is not constant, so the distance and height of the camera should always adjust to the width of Gameobject.

I don't have any approach to solve this problem, so I would be really happy if someone can help me!

Comment: No picture though. If the bounding box is not constant in size, there must be code resizing that. Could you not use the same code to change the camera's depth of field? Or perhaps measure the bounding box every frame and adjust the camera accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually I would say your question is far too broad and basically just searching for a ready to use tool.

Luckily I just happen to have this tool at hand so here you go ^^

```
public static class CameraExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Determines target position and rotation to apply to the perspective <see cref="Camera"/> in order to fit the given <see cref="Bounds"/> into the field of view
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="camera">The <see cref="Camera"/> for which to determine target transformations</param>
    /// <param name="targetPosition">The resulting target position</param>
    /// <param name="targetRotation">The resulting target orientation</param>
    /// <param name="bounds">The <see cref="Bounds"/> to fit into the view of the <see cref="Camera"/></param>
    /// <param name="additionalSpacing">Additional spacing factor (uses <code>(1 + spacing) * boundsSize</code>) to leave free around the given <see cref="Bounds"/></param>
    public static void GetPerspectiveFocusTransforms(this Camera camera, out Vector3 targetPosition, out Quaternion targetRotation, Bounds bounds, float additionalSpacing = 0f)
    {
        var objectSizes = bounds.size;
        var objectSize = Mathf.Max(objectSizes.x, objectSizes.y, objectSizes.z);

        // Visible height 1 meter in front
        var cameraView = 2.0f * Mathf.Tan(0.5f * Mathf.Deg2Rad * camera.fieldOfView);

        // Combined wanted distance from the object
        var distance = (1 + additionalSpacing) * objectSize / cameraView;

        // Estimated offset from the center to the outside of the object
        distance += 0.5f * objectSize;

        targetPosition = bounds.center - distance * camera.transform.forward;
        targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(bounds.center - targetPosition);

        var maxExtent = bounds.extents.magnitude;
        var minDistance = maxExtent * (1 + additionalSpacing) / Mathf.Tan(0.5f * Mathf.Deg2Rad * camera.fieldOfView);
        
        targetPosition = bounds.center - camera.transform.forward * minDistance;

        // camera.nearClipPlane = minDistance - maxExtent;
        targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(bounds.center - targetPosition);
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Determines target position and size to apply to the orthographic <see cref="Camera"/> in order to fit the given <see cref="Bounds"/> into the field of view
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="camera">The <see cref="Camera"/> for which to determine target transformations</param>
    /// <param name="targetPosition">The resulting target position</param>
    /// <param name="targetOrthographicSize">The resulting target size</param>
    /// <param name="bounds">The <see cref="Bounds"/> to fit into the view of the <see cref="Camera"/></param>
    /// <param name="additionalSpacing">Additional spacing factor (uses <code>(1 + spacing) * boundsSize</code>) to leave free around the given <see cref="Bounds"/></param>
    public static void GetOrthographicFocusTransforms(this Camera camera, out Vector3 targetPosition, out float targetOrthographicSize, Bounds bounds, float additionalSpacing = 0f)
    {
        var size = bounds.size;
        var factor = 1 + additionalSpacing;

        var width = size.x * factor;
        var height = size.y * factor;

        if (width > height)
        {
            targetOrthographicSize = Mathf.Abs(width) / camera.aspect / 2f;
        }
        else
        {
            targetOrthographicSize = Mathf.Abs(height) / 2f;
        }

        targetPosition = bounds.center;
        
        targetPosition -= Vector3.Project(targetPosition - camera.transform.position, camera.transform.forward);

        targetOrthographicSize = Mathf.Max(targetOrthographicSize, Mathf.Epsilon);
    }
}
```

So

```
// Depending on whether your camera is perspective
yourCamera.GetPerspectiveFocusTransforms(out var targetPosition, out var targtRotation, yourCollider.bounds);
yourCamera.transform.position = targetPosition;
yourCamera.transform.rotation = targetRotation;

// or orthographic accordingly
yourCamera.GetOrthographicFocusTransforms(out var targetPosition, out var targetSize, yourCollider.bounds);
yourCamera.transform.position = targetPosition;
yourCamera.orthographicSize = targetRotation;
```